# With scala, can I unapply a tuple and then run a map over it?

Tags: scala, tuples

I have some financial data gathered at a List[(Int, Double)], like this:

```
val snp = List((2001, -13.0), (2002, -23.4))
```

With this, I wrote a formula that would transform the list, through map, into another list (to demonstrate investment grade life insurance), where losses below 0 are converted to 0, and gains above 15 are converted to 15, like this:

```
case class EiulLimits(lower:Double, upper:Double)
def eiul(xs: Seq[(Int, Double)], limits:EiulLimits): Seq[(Int, Double)] = {
    xs.map(item => (item._1, 
                    if (item._2 < limits.lower) limits.lower 
                    else if (item._2 > limits.upper) limits.upper 
                         else item._2
}
```

Is there anyway to extract the tuple's values inside this, so I don't have to use the clunky _1 and _2 notation?

Comment: `<console>:6: error: ')' expected but '}' found.` (last curly brace)

Comment: `case Class EiulLimits(lower: Double, upper: Double) { def apply(d: Double) = math.min(upper,math.max(lower,d)) }` is your friend.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
List((1,2),(3,4)).map { case (a,b) => ... }
```

The `case` keyword invokes the pattern matching/unapply logic.

Note the use of curly braces instead of parens after `map`

---

And a slower but shorter quick rewrite of your code:

```
case class EiulLimits(lower: Double, upper: Double) { 
  def apply(x: Double) = List(x, lower, upper).sorted.apply(1)
}

def eiul(xs: Seq[(Int, Double)], limits: EiulLimits) = {
  xs.map { case (a,b) => (a, limits(b)) } 
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> eiul(List((1, 1.), (3, 3.), (4, 4.), (9, 9.)), EiulLimits(3., 7.))
res7: Seq[(Int, Double)] = List((1,3.0), (3,3.0), (4,4.0), (7,7.0), (9,7.0))
```

Comment: Perfect! I like how you have the sort on EiulLimits too. Sorts the right answer into the middle. :)

Comment: For fun, you can see my whole project at https://github.com/gregturn/finance/blob/master/finance.scala. My next step is to using the sliding function, and evaluate every 10, 15, and 20 year interval, to show how much variance there is in overall S&P performance. Who says scala is only for DNA and other scientific research?

Comment: Good answer on how to do the map, but you do realize that you just slowed down the code by a factor of 10, don't you, by creating a list and sorting just to bound a value?

Comment: @Rex Yes, I know it's slower (though whether that matters depends entirely on the usage).  But he already knows the fast solution, so I figured pointing out a short way to do it might be interesting.

Comment: But you did it without warning.  I think it's great to show someone alternate ways to structure their code, but if it's going to be an order of magnitude slower (or change from O(n log n) to O(n^2) or somesuch), it's usually nice to give a warning.

Comment: For the record, I like the sorted solution better, and if it really became a performance issue, I would put back the original solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val snp = List((2001, -13.0), (2002, -23.4))
snp: List[(Int, Double)] = List((2001,-13.0), (2002,-23.4))

scala> snp.map {case (_, x) => x}
res2: List[Double] = List(-13.0, -23.4)

scala> snp.map {case (x, _) => x}
res3: List[Int] = List(2001, 2002)
```